# Update a label when closing Notification Center

Tags: ios, objective-c, integer, uilabel

I think I need some help.

In my App, I do have a `UILabel`, whose text is coming from an "integer". Whenever the `View` loads, it gets the actual in `NSUserDefaults` stored value for the integer:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.sam.Widget"];
counter = [defaults integerForKey:@"MyNumberKey"];
numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter];
```

Also, I do have a NC-Widget, which is performing the same way the app itself does. The value of the "integer" synchronize through App Groups, so when I change the integer's value in the Widget, it stores the value in the `NSUserDefaults`.

So, my problem is, that the second direction (from Widget to App) only works, when the App itself is closed, not even hidden.

So, how can I update the `UILabel` in the App when I close the Notification Center, so that it recognizes the changes I have made to the integer within the widget?

I would appreciate it, if you could help me.
-Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the Notification Center the app goes into background. So you need to catch the event when it goes back into the foreground. You can do this by an observer in your view controller to the system notifications. If you would like to observe your own notifications you can handle these in AppDelegate:
    `applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application`

Don't forget to unsubscribe in dealloc. (it is still being called also in ARC)

```
- (void) handleEnterForeground: (NSNotification*) sender{
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.sam.Widget"];
counter = [defaults integerForKey:@"MyNumberKey"];
numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counter];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
selector: @selector(handleEnterForeground:)
name: @"UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification"
object: nil];
}

- (void)dealloc{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What do I have to add in the AppDelegate? Could you give me the code?

Comment: Replace the method in the app delegate with this: `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"FOREGROUND" object:nil];
}` Don't forget to change the name of your observer to "FOREGROUND" instead of "UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification"